# Submit completed feedback activity

Tags: moodle

I am using the latest version of Moodlecloud. Using a Guest login, how can I submit a completed Feedback activity?

I can open the feedback activity and see/complete all the feedback questions. But there is no Submit button, only a Continue button which doesn't submit. The log reports and have Feedback results using the Continue button, and I have already tried setting permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Guest users do not have permission to complete any actions that write data to the Moodle site - so you can view feedback questions, but you cannot submit the answers.

If you want to submit feedback, you will need a real user account (it may be possible to use a plugin that automatically creates a temporary user account for users that try to access the course with the feedback in it).

Comment: Yes I read that in Moodle docs. But it did mention there was a method to override this in permissions. However, I have not been able to find this. Thanks for your answer, I confirms what I read. Would you know of such a plugin as you mentioned?

Comment: The only such plugins I've come across are similar sorts of things I've developed for specific clients (but which are not available publically and were more 'whole site' automatic logins, for a demo site, rather than logins for a specific course / activity). There may be something suitable in the Moodle plugins DB (try authentication or enrolment plugins).

Comment: Noted. Thanks again for your assistance.